# Project needing script to return number that's between two chosen numbers

Tags: python

The examples are:

```
Type the first number: 2
Type the last number: 8
Choosing a number between 2 and 8.
The number is 7.

Type the first number: -1
Type the last number: 5
Choosing a number between -1 and 5.
The number is -1.
```

What I have been trying code, but never get it to return correctly.

```
import random
first = input('Type the first number: ')
last = input('Type the last number: ')
print('Choosing a number between '+str(first)+' and'+ (last))
roll = random.randint +str
print('The number is ',(roll),'.')
```

I get TypeError unsupported operand type for +: 'method' and 'type' for above code

```
import random
first = input('Type the first number: ')
last = input('Type the last number: ')
print('Choosing a number between '+str(first)+' and'+ (last))
roll = random.randint (first,last)
print('The number is ',(roll),'.')
```

I get TypeError can only concatenate str (not "int") to str for above code

Comment: Please do some basic debugging. `random.randint +str` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: `random.randint` takes `int`, instead of `str`.

Comment: I am new to this, it's my first month into it and the learning process has been absolutely frustrating/hard for me. （◞‸◟）

Answer (score 2):

You HAVE to keep the types straight.

```
import random

first = input('Type the first number: ')
last = input('Type the last number: ')
# At this point, first and last are strings.
# You can print them as strings:

print('Choosing a number between',first,'and',last)

# But, the parameters to randint need to be integers, so you have to convert them:
roll = random.randint(int(first),int(last))

# Now "roll" is an integer.  If you wanted to construct a string from it,
# you would have to convert it, but printing can handle either:
print('The number is ',roll,'.')
# For example:
result = 'The number is ' + str(roll)
result = f'The number is {roll}'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what its still doing but it returns back: The variable 'first' is not the correct value '1' vs 1

Comment: Then you have additional requirements that you didn't share with us.

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code might look something like this:

```
import random

# Get user input and convert them to integers
first = int(input('Type the first number: '))
last = int(input('Type the last number: '))

# Inform the user of the range being used
print('Choosing a number between ' + str(first) + ' and ' + str(last))

# Get a random integer between first and last, inclusive
roll = random.randint(first, last)

# Print the random number
print('The number is ', roll, '.')
```

The function `random.randint()` expects its arguments to be numbers, so we had to convert first and last to ints.

Comment: Ah -- you didn't try this.  That won't work, because you're adding strings and integers in the first print statement.

Comment: Ahh good catch, I fixed it. 

I originally had them in an f-string, but decided to omit that to keep it as simple as possible